# apply to extract Pvalue and list name aov

Tags: r, apply

My data frame below:

```
ID<-c(rep("A", times=5), rep("B", times=5), rep("C", times=5) )
A<-runif(15, 29, 31)
B<-runif(15, 1, 11)
C<-c(runif(5, 0.1, 0.2),NA,NA, runif(3, 10, 11), runif(4, 0.5, 0.52), NA)
D<-runif(15, 2, 7)
df1a<-data.frame(ID,A,B, C, D)
```

I use `apply` to calculate `aov`

```
ss<-apply(df1a[,2:ncol(df1a)], 2, function(x)(summary(aov(x~df1a[,"ID"]))))
```

I want to extract the list name `$C` and `Pr(>F)` using apply. My code is below but it does not work

```
ssp<-apply(df1a[,2:ncol(df1a)], 2, function(x)(summary(aov(x~df1a[,"ID"]))[[1]][["Pr(>F)"]]))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `lapply`

```
lapply(df1a[-1], function(x) summary(aov(x ~ df1a[["ID"]])))[['C']][[1]]$`Pr(>F)`
#[1] 1.404514e-13           NA
```

or using the OP's code with `apply`

```
apply(df1a[,2:ncol(df1a)], 2, function(x)
        (summary(aov(x~df1a[,"ID"]))))[["C"]][[1]][, "Pr(>F)"]
#[1] 1.404514e-13           NA
```

#### Update

If we need all the p-values

```
sapply(df1a[-1], function(x) summary(aov(x ~ df1a[["ID"]]))[[1]][1,'Pr(>F)'])
```

Or as a two column 'data.frame'

```
stack(lapply(df1a[-1], function(x) summary(aov(x ~ df1a[["ID"]]))[[1]][1,'Pr(>F)']))[2:1]
```

Comment: Shall I substitute `[["C"]]` with [[x]] if I want to extract all the pvalues?

Comment: @Al14 Here you can't because your `x` is the column values.  But, if you have looped with names of dataset then you could have done it

Comment: Can you explain it better? Thanks

Comment: @Al14 when you said all the p-values, what do you meant?  Is it to get from all the list elements?

Comment: every pvalue associated to each column (list item) A pvalue, B pvalue, C pvalue

Comment: @Al14  Okay, I thought you are specifically interested in 'C'.  You need `t(sapply(df1a[-1], function(x) summary(aov(x ~ df1a[["ID"]]))[[1]][,'Pr(>F)']))[,1]`